# FIELD TERMINATED BY in MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: java, mysql, csv

I have a function that gives me data about updates/inserts done on a DynamoDb table. For each upsert, I need to parse the data and map it to a corresponding MySQL table schema. I load this data into a file and execute the LOAD DATA INFILE statement provided by MySQL.

My statement looks something like this:

```
LOAD DATA FROM S3 FILE '%s' REPLACE INTO TABLE %s FIELD TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'"
```

And each line in the file might look like this.

> orderNumber123, Mr. ABC, 5th Street New York, 100, 12-12-17

However the problem is that some of the fields within the data contains the comma ','. Now this causes problems because this comma is interpreted by SQL as a terminator of a field.

The fault statement may look like this.

> orderNumber456, Mr. XYZ, 3rd Avenue, New Jersey, 100, 12-12-17

What FIELD TERMINATOR can I provide to avoid this problem? I understand that there is no way to completely prevent this situation but I'm asking what's the best way to make it very unlikely.

I have thought about using tab but that could also be part of the data.

UPDATE:

From the answer provided by [Ike Walker], enclosing the fields by double quotes does the trick. Of course this means I have to decorate my data even further but I suspect that is the only guaranteed way.

Also, if there are any quotes within the field, the SQL statement is intelligent enough to not recognize it as a enclosing character unless it is followed by the terminating character (so in our case `",` would be the cue for termination of a field).
Unfortunately, I have data where this pattern is part of a field. For example,

> {type:long, range: "LONG","INT", amount:100}

To make SQL treat this as a single field, I had to replace each of the double quote by two double quotes.

> {type:long, range: ""LONG"",""INT"", amount:100}

More about this [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html):

> If the field begins with the ENCLOSED BY character, instances of that
>   character are recognized as terminating a field value only if followed
>   by the field or line TERMINATED BY sequence. To avoid ambiguity,
>   occurrences of the ENCLOSED BY character within a field value can be
>   doubled and are interpreted as a single instance of the character. For
>   example, if ENCLOSED BY '"' is specified, quotation marks are handled
>   as shown here:

```
"The ""BIG"" boss"  -> The "BIG" boss
The "BIG" boss      -> The "BIG" boss
The ""BIG"" boss    -> The ""BIG"" boss
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical solution here is to enclose values in quotation marks, at least when the value contains the field separator.

For example you could format your input like this:

```
foo, "hi, I am a value with a comma", bar
```

Then when you load your data you can include this in the `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement:

```
FIELD TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

Comment: It also allows things like `x,"y""z""a",b` where the inner value there has quotes internally. `""` represents a literal quote in that context.

Comment: Oh thats about something I was looking for. However, this does not solve the entire problem. I also have data such as this:

"{key_type:long,range_type:\"LONG\",amount:abc}"

When I parse it into csv, this is what I get,
"{key_type:long,range_type:"LONG",amount:abc}"

So SQL terminates the field after LONG